# Returnning the error page in Hooks / Sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

The documentation seems a bit vague about showing the error page from Hooks. I am looking for a way to show the 404 page conditionally.

```
export async function handle({ event, resolve }) {
  return new Response('This page does not exist.', {status: 404})
}
```

This returns a status 404 page in a plain text, but I want it to return an error page with a layout, not just text. Is there any API to use? Or should I redirect to the 404 page?

Comment: do you have an answer afterall?

Comment: @LazNiko I couldn't find the right solution, from the documentation, nor from the community & web. I just ended up redirecting to the 404 page if the request is not valid. ex) 
    return new Response('This page does not exist.', {status: 302, headers: { Location: '/404' }})

Comment: understood. that would be a solution. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but you can set the `event.route` so that the `resolve` function will return the error page:

```
export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  if (shouldBeNotFound(event)) {
    event.route = {id: null};
  }
 
  const response = await resolve(event);
  return response;
}) satisfies Handle;
```

This will lead `resolve` to think that the page did not match any route of your app, and to render your topmost `+error.svelte`.

Comment: This did not work for me, instead the resolve finishes and displays whatever route was requested.